# Encrypting a secret key for jenkins configuration

Tags: java, python, jenkins, encryption, ansible

I'm automating a Jenkins deployment which involves using the [Google Login](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-login-plugin) plugin using Ansible.
This plugin encrypts the value of the [secret key](https://github.com/jenkinsci/google-login-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/googlelogin/GoogleOAuth2SecurityRealm.java#L114) at rest.

After some digging I found the relevant code which [encrypts secrets in Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/util/Secret.java#L124). The code uses an [AES cypher](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/security/CryptoConfidentialKey.java#L18) and 
custom serialization which appears to be [base64 in a very specific format](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/util/Secret.java#L180).
The encryption key is stored in a CredentialsStore (see [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/security/CryptoConfidentialKey.java#L44) and [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/security/ConfidentialKey.java#L51)).

I'd like to provision the encryption key and the Google Apps secret key using Ansible but I'm not sure how exactly to do so.
I can write a Python module that encrypts the Google Apps secret key the same way Jenkins does but I don't understand how to read or write to the [DefaultCredentialStore](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/security/DefaultConfidentialStore.java#L77).

How do I store my encryption key without using the Java code?
Is there a less tedious way to do this automatically?